# Using condition for each element of a matrix

Tags: procedural-programming, iterators

I'm trying to write a code so that for each element of matrix C2 if the element i,j is equal to element j,i and it is equal to 1 then it adds one to a variable and if not it adds one to another variable. And does this for all powers of the matrix C2. I have already written this, but clearly the if part is wrong.

```
Do[
 C2 = Unitize[MatrixPower[C2, n]], {n, 2, 20};
 If[C2[[i, j]] == C2[[j, i]] && C2[[i, j]] == 1, v++, c++], 
 {i, j} -> {150, 150}]
```

Comment: `if` should be `If`. Your iterator in Do is not in the correct format, you probably want `{i, 1, 150}, {j, 1, 150}` instead. Also, what is the value of `C2`?

Comment: Two problems... `if` should be `If` and `=` should be `==`. I made these changes for you.

Comment: Yes the if was very stupid of me, and even if I allow for {j, 1, 150} it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: C2 can be any matrix for me it is C2 = Table[
RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 100], {j, 1, 100}];

Comment: The first iterator specification `{n, 2, 20}` needs to go with the other two at the end. Something like `Do[..., {n, 2, 20}, {i, 1, 150}, {j, 1, 150}]`. If you're willing to rewrite the condition some, there are much faster ways to solve this problem in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Would you enlighten me how? I tried putting {n, 2, 20} at the end still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
vc[m_] := {#, Times@@Dimensions[m]-#}&[Count[Unitize[c] + Transpose[Unitize[c]], 2, 2]];
```

Generate a random matrix:

```
SeedRandom[17];
c2 = RandomChoice[{1,9}->{1,0}, {150, 150}];
{v, c} = Sum[vc[MatrixPower[c2, n]], {n, 2, 20}]
```

> {418711, 8789}

To explain what's going on here, since `Unitize` will convert the matrix to entirely 0s and 1s, then the condition $M[[i,j]] = M[[j,i]] = 1$ is exactly the same as the condition where $(M+M^T)[[i,j]] = 2$. *Mathematica* can generate $M+M^T$ quite quickly, and similarly can count the number of 2s quite quickly. Since this particular formulation does not require any particular knowledge about where the 2s are (though that could trivially be extracted with `Position`, a simple `Count` suffices. Note that the second argument of `Count` is the pattern we are looking for (`2`), while the third argument is the level to search at (coincidentally also `2` in this case).

`{#, Times@@Dimension[m]-#}&` is an anonymous function (see `&` in the documentation) used to track the parts that don't match the condition (as in variable `c` in your original question) in its second part. Given the number of elements that match (`#`), the number of elements that don't match is the size of the matrix (`Times@@Dimensions[m]`) minus the number that do.

Using the original form of this solution to verify this solution, using some slightly smaller numbers to save CPU time:

```
(* setup *)
SeedRandom[18];
c2 = RandomChoice[{1, 9} -> {1, 0}, {16, 16}];

(* my method *)
{v, c} = Sum[vc[MatrixPower[c2, n]], {n, 2, 20}]
```

> {1173, 3691}

```
(* original solution with bugs fixed *)

v = 0; c = 0;
Do[
  C2 = Unitize[MatrixPower[c2, n]];
  If[C2[[i, j]] == C2[[j, i]] && C2[[i, j]] == 1, v++, c++], {n, 2, 
   20}, {i, 1, 16}, {j, 1, 16}];
{v, c}
```

> {1173, 3691}

The difference in timings is 0.0124s for the first vs 1.496s for the second on my machine.

Comment: The idea of the transpose was fabulous. But I don't find the command that calculates v. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Nishpish: That would be the `Count[Unitize[c] + Transpose[Unitize[c]], 2, 2]` for each individually, and the `Sum` for all of them together.

Comment: Where should I type this? I am currently getting the value of v as zero.

Comment: The answers I get are actually completely different to you, I get v as zero and c as just row . column . (last power-1)

Comment: @Nishpish `{v, c} = Sum[vc[MatrixPower[c2, n]], {n, 2, 20}]` should give exactly the output I presented in my answer (`{1173, 3691}`) with the input matrix in my answer, assuming that the RNG hasn't changed dramatically between versions. That same line should work on any matrix set as `c2` though.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question what you really want to compute. This is my guess.

I will start by showing a function,`counter`, that performs the counting you ask for one $n \times n$ matrix. I will then generate a base matrix, say `m`, consisting of zeros and ones and use it to make a list of the unitized powers of `m` as you describe in your question to use as data. Finally, I will map `counter` over the data to produce a list giving the counts you I think you are asking for. The matrix `m`, is relatively small because I insist on keeping length of this answer to something reasonable.

**Counting function**

```
counter[m_] :=
  Module[{both1 = 0, notBoth1 = 0, n = Length @ m},
    Do[If[m[[i, j]] == m[[j, i]] && m[[i, j]] == 1, both1++, notBoth1++],
       {i, n}, {j, n}];
    {both1, notBoth1}]
```

**Base matrix**

SeedRandom[42]; m = RandomChoice[{.8, .2} -> {0, 1}, {10, 10}];

**Test data**

```
powers = Table[Unitize[MatrixPower[m, n]], {n, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
>  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
>  {{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}}, 
>  {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
> ```

**Mapping over the data**

```
counter /@ powers
```

```
{{11, 89}, {39, 61}, {70, 30}, {92, 8}}
```